# How to create a collection of Border elements in WrapPanel from an ItemsSource in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

I want to repeat the `Border` element inside the outer `WrapPanel`:

```xml
<WrapPanel x:Name="filterWrapper" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FilterName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="x"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Border>
</WrapPanel>
```

This is the depending class:

```cs
public class FilterField
{
    public String FilterName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a collection of `FilterField` objects, which should result in:

```xml
<WrapPanel x:Name="filterWrapper" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Test_1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="x"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Test_2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="x"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Test_3"/>
            <TextBlock Text="x"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Border>
</WrapPanel>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I assume you do have a collection of ``FilterField`` objects somewhere, right?

Comment: Yes, sure. It's in the main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ItemsControl` to display a collection of items with a specific template in a specific `Panel`:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <!-- Place all items in a WrapPanel -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel x:Name="filterWrapper" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <!-- Define the look of each item -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpfapp1:FilterField}">
            <Border>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FilterName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="x"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `DataTemplate` you define in `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` gets applied to all items in the source collection, and each item gets added in the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` that you define, here a `WrapPanel`.

This is assuming you have a a collection `Items` of type `List<FilterField>` in your view model, like this:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}

public class MyViewModel {
    public List<FilterField> Items { get; set; } = new List<FilterField> {
        new FilterField() { FilterName = "Test_1"},
        new FilterField() { FilterName = "Test_2"},
        new FilterField() { FilterName = "Test_3"},
    };
}

public class FilterField {
    public string FilterName { get; set; }
}
```